# store file in object state using hooks react

Tags: reactjs, filepond

When I upload a file , file is stored in state. But I got an error like

GET http://localhost:3000/type/%5Bobject%20File%5D 404 (Not Found).

Why it is occured?Please help me.
My code is

```
 <FilePond
          ref={pond}
          files={formData.applicantPhoto}
          name="applicantPhoto"
          allowMultiple={false}
          required
          maxFiles={1}
          labelIdle={
            'Drag & Drop your Applicant Photo or <span class="filepond--label-action"> Browse </span>'
          }
          server={{
            process: (
              fieldName,
              file,
              metadata,
              load,
              error,
              progress,
              abort
            ) => {
              getFiles(
                fieldName,
                file,
                metadata,
                load,
                error,
                progress,
                abort
              );
            },
          }}
        />
 const getFiles = async (
      fieldName,
      file,
      metadata,
      load,
      error,
      progress,
     abort
   ) => {
     console.log(pond.current.getFile().file);
     const image = await pond.current.getFile().file;
     setFormData({ ...formData, applicantPhoto: image });
   };
```

How to store file object in object state. Please help me.When add file in syncronous mode , that also gives same error.

Comment: could you share sandbox with the code? what you are trying to do ? just send a file to server?

Comment: I have to store file in state which is object. initially I tried onUpdateFiles function. it doesn't work . so I tried in server function.

Comment: could you provide simple sandbox ? i could try help you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-murdock-3dgkc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1.Set the URL of the file object inside the state and then parse it back to the file object in your submit function.

2.Use the file's data return to you from the library,set that on state and use that inside the submit function...(easier and how the library works from the docs).

you can see that here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fog-fcl5e?file=/src/FileUpload.js

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to store in a state the url (via `URL.createObjectURL()` the browser will take care of the rest) as state is not intended for binary data (even more so when it comes to Redux), although it can of course be stored, but it causes an overhead.

I used `selectedFile` for keep file, and `file` to keep url

Оf course, if you need to send a file to the `backend`, then you need to send thie `selectedFile`, but there is no reason to store it on the `frontend`, the link made will be enough, the rest will be done by caching.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Load our React component. -->
      <script type="text/babel">
        window.useState = React.useState;
        window.useEffect = React.useEffect

        const FileUploadPage = () => {
          const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
          const [file, setFile] = useState('')
    
          const handleChange = (event)=> {
            setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
            setFile(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
          }

          return (
            <div>
              <input type="file" onChange={handleChange}/>
              {
                file && (
                  <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column' }} >
                    <img src={file} height="200" width="300"/>  
                    <p>Filename: {selectedFile.name}</p>
                    <p>Filetype: {selectedFile.type}</p>
                    <p>Size in bytes: {selectedFile.size}</p>
                  </div>
                )
              }  
            </div>
          );
        }
      
        const App = () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <FileUploadPage/>
            </div>
          );
        };

        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: got an error. Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.

Comment: what is your Browser? I tested this code in Firefox and Chromium

Comment: my browser is chrome

Comment: It's the same as chromium. Doesn't work my snippet?

Comment: <FilePond
              ref={pond}
              files={formData.applicantPhoto}
              allowMultiple={false}
              allowFileEncode={true}
              required={true}
              labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span className="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
              onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                setFormData({
                  ...formData,
                  applicantPhoto: fileItems.map((fileItem) => fileItem.file),
                });
              }}
            />